# Why is it called "lunch" in AOSP Building?

Tags: android, android-source

I came across the AOSP Build process and the command "lunch".

See: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building#lunch

Can somebody explain, why it was called "lunch"? What the intention behind?

Comment: Found: `To select the set of things you want to build, and what items to build for, you use either the 'choosecombo' function or the 'lunch' function. 'choosecombo' will walk you through the different items you have to select, one-by-one, while 'lunch' allows you select some pre-set combinations.` from https://elinux.org/Android_Build_System